Passing HTTP fields for Dapr pub/sub Redis
I'm trying to pass a header (Idempotency-Key) between Dapr services. It seems that these fields are not delivered on the subscriber side.
Alternatively, metadata are only restricted to a few fields.
There is an option of extending my paylad with this data, but I'm trying to avoid it, since naturally it belongs in headers.
I tried setting the header value and message is sent, but on the receiving side, this data (custom header) is not present. I'm using Redis as the broker.

Also looking for a solution to capture header information from the message in the broker and have Dapr send that as headers to the subscription API. Only solution i've seen for now is using the state component and save that context to the state store. You could use that state store as intermediate between pub/sub too instead of saving state on publish and retrieve state on subscribe but you'd still need a key. Also requested here: https://github.com/dapr/dapr/issues/6075
